# HarmonyOS API toolchain 6 not found

Tags: sdk, harmonyos, deveco-studio

[image: Deveco settings]

I'm getting this error:

```
SdkError: DOWNLOAD_SDK_ERROR
     > Cause: Unable to find the following components:
        toolchains:6
     > Solution: 
        1.Go to Tools > SDK Manager > SDK > HarmonyOS, download the components, and sync the project with Gradle file.
        2.Alternatively, modify the compileSdkVersion settings in the project- and module-level build.gradle files.
```

I have tried downloading it manually, but I can't see API 6 in the list.

How can I get API 6 toolchain?